# Change mouse to cursor pointer whenever hover over visualforce chart in salesforce

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visualforce-charting

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController" title="Pie Chart" sidebar="false">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ChartLib, 'jquery.min.js')}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    function funtest() {
       j$('svg').css('cursor','hand');
       j$('rect').css('cursor','pointer');
       j$('path').css('cursor','pointer');       
    }
</script>

<apex:chart height="450" width="450" data="{!pieData}">
    <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name" rendererFn="funtest" showInLegend="false"/>
    <apex:legend position="right"/>
</apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

controller

```
public class ChartController {

    public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() {

        List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Jan', 30));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Feb', 15));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Mar', 10));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Apr', 20));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('May', 20));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Jun', 5));
        return data;
    }
// Wrapper class
    public class PieWedgeData {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public Integer data { get; set; }
        public PieWedgeData(String name, Integer data) {
            this.name = name;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

All I'm doing is to render the data on a VF page via visual force chart.
As per requirement, I'm supposed to change the mouse cursor to a pointer(i.e. hand) whenever a user hovers over within graph area.
I did that using SVG which is applicable to complete pie chart.

Is there anyway with which I can change the mouse cursor to pointer whenever the tooltip is visible to a user or whenever any specific portion pops out?

Any help or inputs are much appreciated!

Thank you.
Regards,
Pooja

Comment: Hey Pooja.. It is already showing Hand.. When I hover the chart it is showing hand  curser only..

Comment: Yes it is as I'm using SVG. But as per requirement it should only be for a specific area like when I'm hovering over Jan then Jan area pops out. Further on click of Jan I'm supposed to open one more VF page. As my cursor to pointer is via SVG its applicable to complete chart and not to specific section of chart

Answer (score 3):

Please include below style css in your vf page and have a try:

```
<style type="text/css">
.vf-surface {
cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Pooja, if above code works please mark my reply as Answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Rv1! Let me rephrase my question one more time. Imagine with above code visual force pie chart is visible with proper data in it. Now whenever, user moves cursor over pie chart then visual force chart automatically sliced out the section. Per my requirement, i need to change the mouse cursor to pointer(i.e. hand) whenever such slice pops out due to hover over by mouse. Any guidance is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Yes,Pooja. Have u tried the above? The pie chart which was created will have the class "vf-surface" (partially). If you include above lines in ur code, it will give Pointer(hand) form. Please check.

Comment: This is what is I've done and able to achieve so far!

Comment: This is what is I've done and able to achieve so far! One can see that whenever user hovers over pie chart, visualforce chart slice out that particular part so that end user can notice plus can read related tool tip. Now I've slight addition to my original requirement, I need to change mouse cursor to pointer plus I need to increase the font size of the text for a specific hover section. Code is as follows-

Comment: <apex:page controller="ChartController" title="Pie Chart" sidebar="false"> <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ChartLib, 'jquery.min.js')}"/> <script type="text/javascript"> j$=jQuery.noConflict();function funtest(){j$('path,tspan').css('cursor','pointer');var oldSize=parseFloat(j$('text').css('font-size'));var newSize = oldSize*2;j$('path, tspan').mouseover(function() {j$('tspan').css('font-size',newSize);});j$('path,tspan').mouseleave(function(){j$('tspan').css('font-size',oldSize);});} </script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> j$=jQuery.noConflict();function funtest(){j$('path,tspan').css 'cursor','pointer');var  oldSize=parseFloat(j$('text').css('font-size'));var newSize=oldSize*2;    j$('path,tspan').mouseover(function(){j$('tspan').css('font-size',newSize);});j$('path,tspan').mouseleave(function (){j$('tspan').css('font-size',oldSize);});}</script>

Comment: This code is changing font size across 'tspan' selector which is wrong for me as I need to change the font size only on hover section area and NOT across all 'tspan'. I would appreciate any input.